# Getting a value from a pandas df with specific indexing and filtering

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, filter

I have the following dataframe:

```
df
                                         eff   inv-cost  fix-cost  var-cost  inst-cap  cap-lo        cap-up  wacc  depreciation  annuity-factor
Site In Site Out Transmission Commodity                                                                                                        
Mid     North    hvac         Elec       0.9  1650000.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0  1.500000e+15  0.07          40.0        0.075009
        South    hvac         Elec       0.9  1650000.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0  1.500000e+15  0.07          40.0        0.075009
North   Mid      hvac         Elec       0.9  1650000.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0  1.500000e+15  0.07          40.0        0.075009
        South    hvac         Elec       0.9  1650000.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0  1.500000e+15  0.07          40.0        0.075009
South   Mid      hvac         Elec       0.9  1650000.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0  1.500000e+15  0.07          40.0        0.075009
        North    hvac         Elec       0.9  1650000.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0  1.500000e+15  0.07          40.0        0.075009
```

I would like to get the values in `Site In` and `Site Out` as a list consist of tuples. Below there is an example of the list I would like to have:

```
list = [('Mid','North'),
        ('South', 'Mid'),
        ('South', 'North')]
```

Key point here is getting the values from `Site In` and `Site Out` with a pandas function as easy as possible, and also since the transmission from `'Mid'` to `'South'` is equal with the transmission from `'South'` to `'Mid'`, some of the created elements of the list should be filtered.

Following would be what I thought so far but maybe u could find a better way?

1) get values of `Site In` and `Site Out` and create a list, the list will probably look like this:

```
list = [('Mid','North'), ('Mid','South'),
        ('North', 'Mid'), ('North', 'South'),
        ('South', 'Mid'), ('South', 'North')]
```

2) since half of the elements are equal and not necessary such as; `('Mid','North')` & `('North', 'Mid')`, one of them could be removed.

3) In the end I would like to have any of the following (order is not relevant):

```
list = [('Mid','North'), ('Mid','South'), ('North', 'South')]
list = [('North','Mid'), ('Mid','South'), ('North', 'South')]
list = [('South','Mid'), ('Mid','North'), ('North', 'South')]
etc...
```

**Source for df**
Transmission Sheet of
https://github.com/rl-institut/urbs-oemof/blob/dev/mimo.xlsx

**PS:**
I don't know which pandas function to use to get 1st item, also don't know how to pop elements mentioned in 2nd item. And if u also have a better algorithm for this I would gladly use it. TY

Comment: Your question will be more likely to be answered if you give us the way you generated your multiindexed df as this is not the easiest thing to replicate on our own.

Comment: question edited @d_kennetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for:

for step 1: just get the index values:

```
# reset the index so that 'Site In' and 'Site Out' are left
lis = list(df.reset_index(level=[2,3]).index.values)

[('Mid', 'North'),
 ('Mid', 'South'),
 ('North', 'Mid'),
 ('North', 'South'),
 ('South', 'Mid'),
 ('South', 'North')]
```

then use `set` with some list comprehension:

```
list(set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in lis))

[('Mid', 'North'), ('Mid', 'South'), ('North', 'South')]
```

I am assuming your multiindex looks like:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Mid', 'North', 'South'], ['Mid', 'North', 'South'], ['hvac'], ['Elec']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=['Site In', 'Site Out', 'Transmission', 'Commodity'])
```

Comment: I am gonna check it tomorrow, probably it works. then I accept your answer :) ty @Chris